# 302 Redirects seemingly happening before mvc routing. Help debugging redirects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, extjs, iis-7

*Update!*
So I thought I had this solved - and it's come back. My ignore routes are seemingly being ignored. Every request is being redirected :(

I've got an MVC site I'm working on, the majority of it is in EXTJS, so they are only using a single controller, home and login views. Pretty standard setup - and this was working last week, the Index action is called on the Home controller, it is immediately redirected to the login action. Okay - great, that's expected behaviour.

Only now, each and every linked file, css or javascript, is redirected back to the same login page. The exception to this are a couple script files fetched via a rest Uri. So I downloaded that route debugger being passed around here and passed it the url to one of the script files. It was instantly reformatted and redirected to the login page with a returnurl parameter set to the file I was looking for. This is making me think that requests are being redirected before hitting any of mvc's routes. Is this possible? What are further steps I could take to debug this issue?

Here are the routing contents of my global.asax file:

```
/// <summary>
  /// Registers the routes.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="routes">The routes.</param>
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
  {
     routes.IgnoreRoute(@"{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
     routes.IgnoreRoute(@"resources/*"); //Redirecting!! Css and image files
     routes.IgnoreRoute(@"wcfrestbusinesslogic/*"); //This one works fine
     routes.IgnoreRoute(@"ext/*"); //These are also redirecting

     routes.IgnoreRoute(@"{*favicon}",
                        new
                        {
                           favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?"
                        });

     routes.MapRouteLowercase(@"PasswordReset",
                              @"{action}/{guid}",
                              new
                              {
                                 controller = @"home",
                                 action = @"index"
                              },
                              new
                              {
                                 IsHome = new IsHomeActionConstraint(),
                                 guid = @"^(\{{0,1}([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}\}{0,1})$"
                              });

     routes.MapRouteLowercase(@"Home",
                              @"{action}/{output}",
                              new
                              {
                                 controller = @"home",
                                 action = @"index",
                                 output = UrlParameter.Optional
                              },
                              new
                              {
                                 IsHome = new IsHomeActionConstraint(),
                                 output = @"(json|xml|pdf|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png|csv)?"
                              });

     routes.MapRouteLowercase(@"Home2",
                              @"{action}/{id}/{output}",
                              new
                              {
                                 controller = @"home",
                                 action = @"index",
                                 id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                                 output = UrlParameter.Optional
                              },
                              new
                              {
                                 IsHome = new IsHomeActionConstraint(),
                                 id = @"[0-9]{1,}",
                                 output = @"(json|xml|pdf)?"
                              });

     routes.MapRouteLowercase(@"Home3",
                              @"{action}",
                              new
                              {
                                 controller = @"home",
                                 action = @"index"
                              },
                              new
                              {
                                 IsHome = new IsHomeActionConstraint()
                              });

     routes.MapRoute(@"Action",
                     @"{controller}/{action}/{output}",
                     new
                     {
                        controller = @"Home",
                        action = @"Index",
                        output = UrlParameter.Optional
                     },
                     new
                     {
                        output = @"(json|xml|pdf|png|csv)?"
                     });

     routes.MapRoute(@"Default",
                     @"{controller}/{action}/{id}/{output}",
                     new
                     {
                        controller = @"Home",
                        action = @"Index",
                        id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                        output = UrlParameter.Optional
                     },
                     new
                     {
                        id = @"[0-9]{1,}",
                        output = @"(json|xml|pdf)?"
                     });


  }
```

Comment: Have you checked your web.config file? Any forms authentication configuration or things like that?

Comment: It's the default line:
    <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms name="auth" domain="" loginUrl="~/login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

Comment: See my answer for how I solved my issue - these routing/auth suggestions are worth keeping as the real answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the solution turned out to be related to SVN. I had to revert to a time that the site had worked, and overwrite from that point with the latest update. Something was cached somewhere and I'm not sure what fixed it, but if you run into this issue and none of the solutions posted help - look into your source control.

Thanks for your help everyone.

**UPDATE**
The svn thing was only part of the problem, and it wasn't svn itself - but the permissions that were changing on certain files in the project from each developer.

The problem returned when our computer names were changed over the weekend.

The real source of the issue was IIS' anonymous authentication was set to use IUSR, but it should have been set to use the ApplicationPoolIdentity.

Since the way IUSR works by appending the computer name, the permissions on the files from SVN were all set to our old names, and so when IIS tried to fetch anything with those permissions, it would fail and be redirected to the login page - before even hitting MVC's route manager.

**UPDATE 2**
Encountered this problem again, this time some web.config files were accessed on my machine via sharing them, and this 302 thing started happening. It revealed that setting mentioned above was set incorrectly in iis.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your Forms Authentication is protecting the files.

Do you have anything like this in your Web.Config?

```
<location path="resources">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="ext">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Yes - this is seemingly ignored. Are there any IIS settings or anything that is checked before the web.config and mvc routing?

Comment: Sorry to retract the answer but this issue has come back, even with these in my IIS.

Comment: @Gallen you still having the issue?  This answer helped me.  All unauthenticated requests were being re-directed unless I added path entry in the web.config as specified.